# Cleanup blocking resources in Node.js after main process is done

Tags: node.js, child-process

I have a long-running child process that I reuse across function calls, for performance reasons, but I do not want the child process to block the main process and keep it from exiting. Currently I work around it by explicitly calling a function that safely exits the child process, but ideally I would make this an implmentation detail and hide it from the API.

Since I don't know which of the function calls that uses the child process is the last, I was hoping there was a way to know when the main process is done, but waiting for its child processes to end, so that I can safely exit the child process at that moment.

I had hoped `beforeExit` would do this for me, but when I tried experimenting with it, I could not make it to work for my use case.

Here is an example:

```
// Implementation...
import * as child_process from "node:child_process"
const reusedProc = child_process.spawn("long-running")
function call() {
    // some communication with `reusedProc`
}
function exitLongRunning() {
    // safely exits `reusedProc`
}

// Usage...
call()
call()
exitLongRunning()
```

I want to reuse the long-running child process throughout the program whenever `call` is used, but I would love `exitLongRunning` to not be part of the API, but just part of the implementation that adds some necessary hook to make the call to `exitLongRunning` itself.

So the implementation would contain (pseudo code):

```
process.on('waitingOnChildren', () => {
  exitLongRunning()
})
```

And usage would no longer need to call `exitLongRunning` explicitly, i.e.:

```
call()
call()
```

Is this possible in Node?

Note that I already use [`node-cleanup`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cleanup) to cleanup other resources, but since the main process is being blocked by the child process, it never exits, so the cleanup is never triggered either, and thus it does not seem a solution for this situation.

Comment: Is the `detached` option for `spawn()` related to what  you want?  That would make the child's lifetime independent from the parent's lifetime and vice versa.  I'm asking because I don't really understand what you want.  There is also `child.unref()` that keeps the parent from waiting for the child to finish.

Comment: AFAIK you will need `detached: true`, `stdio: "ignore"`, and `child.unref()` for that to work, but that will make the child process completely isolated, meaning no more communication between child and parent process. I am thinking of using named pipes to workaround blocking the main process. I had hoped I was pretty clear in what I want. I don't want to have to have to explicitly close the child process, but have this be done at the end of running the program, but the end events (`exit` and such) are not called when there is still a child process running.

Comment: Well, you either have the two processes connected so they can communicate or you don't.  If they are connected, then they will keep each other alive from automatic program exit because the communication channel is alive.  Unless you `.unref()` whatever the communication channel is.  Then, that won't keep the process alive by itself.  Of course, if the child or parent just calls `process.exit()` when its done, then you aren't relying on automatic process exit and you don't have to worry about the things that might be keeping the process alive and `process.exit()` ignores those.

Comment: I knew all that. I think I should rephrased my question a bit, as in the end all I really want to know is when the last function call to `call` is made, so I can cleanup the state behind `call`. In this case the long-running child process. And the only way I could think of doing so is `beforeExit`/`exit`. So I ended up working around the child process preventing `beforeExit` from being emitted, by disconnecting the processes like you mention, but still have communication through the use of named pipes.

Comment: Well, it was pretty hard to parse that out of your question.

Comment: Well, I did say it in the second paragraph: "Since I don't know which of the function calls that uses the child process is the last, I was hoping there was a way to know when the main process is done". But yeah, I could probably have stated things better. I find it a hard question to properly put into words though. Simplify it too much and people will ask why you need to know the last call. Give too much context, and I am in my current situation where the original intent might be obscured a bit by context.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is we want to leverage the `beforeExit` or `exit` events of the main process to handle the cleanup of the long-running child process. Yet we want to maintain the ability to communicate back-and-forth with the child process, which would prevent them from being emitted. My current solution is to fully detach the child process from the main process, and because any form of communication between the child and main process would prevent `beforeExit` from being emitted, we handle the communication outside of Node, through the use of named pipes. And the child process can be send a kill message in `beforeExit` or `nodeCleanup`.

It requires more glue than I like, as I now have:
`main -(disconnected)-> intermediate child -(connected)-> intended child`
Where `main` and `intermediate child` communicate through named pipes.

Here is a full example:

`main.ts`

```
import * as nodeCleanup from "node-cleanup"
import * as child_process from "node:child_process"
import * as fs from "node:fs"
import * as fsp from "node:fs/promises"
import * as process from "node:process"

function spawnSync(cmd: string, args: ReadonlyArray<string> = []) {
  const proc = child_process.spawnSync(cmd, args, { encoding: "utf8" })
  if (proc.error) {
    console.error(proc.error)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  if (proc.status != 0) {
    console.error(proc.stderr)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  return proc
}

function createPipe() {
  const pipePath = spawnSync("mktemp", [
    `--tmpdir=${process.env.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}`,
    "--dry-run",
    "pipe.XXXXXXXX",
  ]).stdout.trimEnd()
  spawnSync("mkfifo", ["-m", "600", pipePath])
  return pipePath
}

const writePipe = createPipe()
const readPipe = createPipe()

async function send(message: string) {
  await fsp.writeFile(writePipe, message, "utf8")
  return fsp.readFile(readPipe, "utf8")
}

const forked = child_process.fork("./child", {
  env: Object.assign({}, process.env, { WRITE_PIPE: readPipe, READ_PIPE: writePipe }),
  stdio: "ignore",
  detached: true,
})
forked.disconnect()
forked.unref()

nodeCleanup(() => {
  fs.writeFileSync(writePipe, "kill", "utf8")
  spawnSync("rm", [writePipe, readPipe])
})

async function main() {
  console.log(await send("message"))
}
main()

process.on("beforeExit", () => {
  console.log("before exit")
})
```

`intermediate.ts`

```
import * as child_process from "node:child_process"
import * as fs from "node:fs"
import * as fsp from "node:fs/promises"
import * as process from "node:process"

const KILL_MESSAGE = "kill"

const writePipe = process.env.WRITE_PIPE!
const readPipe = process.env.READ_PIPE!

const child = child_process.spawn("long-running")
child.stdout?.on("data", (data) => {
  const lines = data.toString().replace("\n$", "").split("\n")
  for (const line of lines) {
    fs.writeFileSync(writePipe, line, "utf8")
  }
})

async function main() {
  for (;;) {
    const message = await fsp.readFile(readPipe, "utf8")
    if (message === KILL_MESSAGE) process.exit(0)
    writeToChild(message)
  }
}
main()
```